# Find how "smooth" a number is based on binary

Tags: code-golf, binary, base-conversion

I haven't been on PP&CG for a while, so I thought I would post something!

Your task is to find how "smooth" a *natural* number is. Your method is to:

1: Convert the number to binary
2: Find the number of changes / switches
3: Find the length of the string (in binary)
4: Divide length by changes

So, an example. 5.
Starting at step one, we wind up with 101 for binary.
Step two is where we count the "switches". This is how many times a digit changes, so 100001 would count 2 switches. 101 counts 2, too.
Step three has a length of three in binary.
Step four gives us 3/2, or 1.5.
Doing this for 10 is also simple: Step one results with 1010, two with three, three with four, and a final result has 1.33333333... repeating.

If the inputs output infinity (examples: `1`, `3`, and `7`), you need to output something that tells you infinity, like \$\infty\$ or `Infinity`.

Now, you might ask, "*what about scoring?*" or something like that: You are scored in characters, so feel free to use a lot of code golfing languages. (*I'm looking at you, Jelly*)
If you round the output "smoothness factor" to 3 decimal places (4/3 is now 1.333, 5/3 is 1.667) your score is now x0.95, and being able to not only return a smoothness factor but also be able to compare two numbers (etc: putting in 5 and 10 returns > because 5's smoothness factor is greater than 10's) multiplies your value by x0.7. Command-line flags don't count for anything.
Have fun!

This challenge **ends** the 19th of March.
Current placeholders: The functional language holder, with 45 chars, Nahuel Fouilleul, and the code golf language holder, with 7 chars, Luis Mendo.

Comment: It would be a bit clearer if both examples were given separately. Also, I don't think the bonuses add much to the challenge.

Comment: welcome to PPCG! You've been around for a month or so, but I would suggest using [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback on your challenges before posting them.

Comment: Inputs `1`, `3`, `7` etc give infinity. Should we really output infinity for those?

Comment: No. If you put in `5 10`, you will get `>`, but `10 5` gives `<`.

Comment: ? I don't quite clearly understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: What is the reason for the complexity around scoring?

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this challenge due to the complexity around the scoring and the ambiguous-ness related to it.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are going to select an accepted answer at least wait 1 week

Comment: And if you do accept an answer, it should be the best one according to your own cumbersome scoring system.

Comment: I don't really see the point of scoring in characters. Almost all golfing languages, e.g. Jelly, have the same amount of bytes as characters anyway, so your reasoning isn't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl 5 (`-p -Mbignum`), 45 bytes

```
$_=sprintf"%b",$_;$_=y///c/(s/(.)(?!\1)//g-1)
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRNSTVJSUcl3hooUqmvr5@sr1Gsr6GnqWGvGGOoqa@frmuo@f@/KZehAZchlzGX@b/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFOf91fZMy0/NKcwE)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 characters

```
Btnwdz/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36kkrzylSv//f0MDAA)

#### Explanation

```
B    % Convert to binary
t    % Duplicate
n    % Number of elements
w    % Swap
d    % Consecutive differences
z    % Number of nonzeros
/    % Divide
```

Comment: Honestly, how it it possible to incorporate 7 ASCII characters to make a complicated program like the one I described. I don't understand code golf anymore.

Comment: @Ethan Wait for the 4-byte Jelly or 05AB1E answers...

Comment: Note that in my *original* post I said you would be counted by chars, not bytes. Still stands.

Comment: @EthanSlota MATL is at least pretty easy to understand, since for the most part, each command is a MATLAB or Octave command and there's a parser built in Octave / MATLAB. This would translate to something like `@(x,b=dec2bin(x))numel(b)/nnz(diff(b))` but it uses Luis' much terser language to achieve the same result.

Comment: @EthanSlota: Counting by chars instead of bytes can only make the scores even lower.

Comment: @LuisMendo I doubt I will find any 4-byters in 05AB1E. ;) Currently sitting at 8 tbh.. >.>

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how this hasn't been passed yet. And in ASCII!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

*NULL for infinity*

```
¤Ê/¢ä¦ x
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pMovouSmIHg=&input=MTA=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/Code-page), score 8

<sub>Maybe there is a terser way... edit: I don't think there is.</sub>

```
BL÷BITLƲ
```

Infinity is given as `inf`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/J5/B2J88Qn2Ob/v//bwwA)**

...other 8's are possible too, for example `BµITL÷@L` or `BL÷BnƝSƊ`.

Comment: Here’s a version to get the bonuses: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4a6Ow9udPEMeNa0BMo9tOrysyFjH8@HOBSr///83NNAxBQA) score 16 x 0.95 x 0.7 = 10.64

Comment: Shouldn't `inf` be greater than all other values? If we can identify `inf` as less than all others we could accept a list of either one or two numbers and have `BL÷BITLƲ),M` for 11 * 0.7 = 7.7. (Maybe this comparison should be fixed...)

Comment: ...BTW that isn't doing what you think `IṠ$` is acting on the input list itself so it's just telling you that 10 is greater than 5 rather than comparing the smoothness of the two numbers.

Comment: Thanks - still getting my head around Jelly. This seems better: [tio](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4a6Ow9udPEMeNa0BMo9tOrysyPjQVh3PhzsX@B3r@v//v6mOkSkA) but is two bytes longer

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>46 44</s>  40 bytes / characters

Returns `Infinity` if there's no bit flip.

```javascript
n=>(g=s=>n&&1+g(x=s-(n^(n>>=1))%2))``/~x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclLCoAgEADQffcoZog@Ri7Ho4RSJkWMkRGuurq1jbbvreYyYTyW/azYTzbNlJgUOAqkuChE6SBSqIAHYKVIIOYdotbNHdPoOfjN1pt3MMNb2VfkT0T7o072iOkB)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                  // n = input integer
  g = s =>              // g = recursive function taking the number s of bit switches
    n &&                //   stop if n is equal to 0
    1 +                 //   otherwise, add 1 to the final returned value
    g(                  //   and do a recursive call to g:
      x =               //     update s and save the result in x:
        s -             //       subtract 1 from s if ...
        (n ^ (n >>= 1)) //       ... there is a bit switch; and shift n to the right
        % 2             //       NB: an extra bit switch is counted on the last bit
    )                   //   end of recursive call
)``                     // initial call to g with s = [''], which is coerced to 0
                        // as soon as something is subtracted from it
/ ~x                    // divide the result of g by -(x + 1), which compensates for
                        // the extra switch
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)/characters

```
bgIbγg</
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Kd0z6dzmdBv9//9NAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/pPTKpHOb0230/@v8jzbVMTTQMdQx1jGPBQA).

Or alternatively:

```
b©g®¥ÄO/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6dDK9EPrDi093OKv//@/KQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/pEMr0w@tO7T0cIu//n@d/9GmOoYGOoY6xjrmsQA).

Outputs `0.0` for the `INF` cases.

---

With both bonuses **score: 11.97 (18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)/characters * 0.95 * 0.7)**:

```
εbgybγg</3.ò}DÆ.±)
```

Outputs `1` if the first input is larger than the second; `-1` if vice-versa; `0` if they are equal.
NOTE: Because I output `0.0` for the `INF` cases, they are considered lower than non-infinity test cases. Let me know if this has to be fixed..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Nak9Mqkc5vTbfSN9Q5vqnU53KZ3aKPm///RpjqGBrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε       # Map both values of the (implicit) input-list:
 b      #  Get the binary-string of the current value
  g     #  And get the length of this string
 yb     #  Get the binary-string of the current value again
   γ    #  Split it into chunks of equal adjacent digits
    g<  #  Get the amount of chunks, and subtract 1
 /      #  Divide both numbers
 3.ò    #  Round the number to 3 decimal values
}D      # After the map: duplicate the resulting list
  Æ     # Reduce the duplicated list by subtraction
   .±   # And get the sign of that result
     )  # Then wrap it into a list with the mapped values
        # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: For clarification, ∞ ≠ 0.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, but 05AB1E doesn't have an infinite value (unless you count the infinite list). And since regular cases which divide `x` by `y` can **never** result in `0` anyway, I use that to indicate infinity (the challenge description states "_you need to output something that tells you infinity_", which is `0.0` in my answer). If the infinite list or an empty string or something has to be output instead of 0 it's 3 bytes more, although I don't really see the point..

Comment: I'll accept this answer as valid as there are no fractions that *naturally* result in zero. You would need to define something (like `5/1 = 0 = Infinity`) to get 0.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```
{s->s.toString(2).run{length.toFloat()/(0..length-2).count{this[it]!=this[it+1]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xC8IwEIX3/orrdkEaraNQR0Fwc5QOodY2GC/SXF1Cfnu8Vm86Hh/ve0/PzlL@GAePmboD4JlYQXWEk/OGockxVMeg2V95sjTgXulppuh6GniUeMVQbXGn9S@sBOn8TBx5tOFmuS2b/7ep25RSFhO8jCVUEAuQW/TcB9HB1Jv7xVKPqiylXtagWpm36NkRLjNxgZUqUq6/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Python 3, 131 bytes (154 with file header)

Hi. I know that my code is way longer than others, but I will try it ;) Indentation by tabs.

Script takes sequence of numbers in aguments and prints "smoothness" for each argument on own line. If number of changes is 0, prints "inf".

```
$ ./script.py 12
4.0

$ ./script.py 12 5 6
4.0
1.5
3.0

$ ./script.py `seq 5`
None
2.0
None
3.0
1.5
```

file header

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

code

```
import sys
for n in sys.argv[1:]:
    b=bin(int(n))[2:];c=0;l=b[0]
    for o in b:
        if o!=l:c+=1
        l=o
    print(len(b)/c if c>0 else"inf")
```

### Input single number from STDIN: 102+23 bytes (code + file header)

```
n=input();b=bin(int(n))[2:];c=0;l=b[0]
for o in b:
    if o!=l:c+=1
    l=o
print(len(b)/c if c>0 else"inf")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

```r
length(y<-(x=scan())%/%2^(0:log2(x))%%2)/sum(diff(y)!=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyc1L70kQ6PSRlejwrY4OTFPQ1NTVV/VKE7DwConP91IowLIVzXS1C8uzdVIyUxL06jUVLQ10Pxv@h8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 characters

```
≔⍘Ｎ²θ≔⁺№θ10№θ01η¿ηＩ∕Ｌθη∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DKbE4NbikKDMvXcMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTR8EIiAs1rbmgCgNySos1nPNL80o0CnUUlAwNlIDyCL6BoZImUCADqCEzTUEjQ1MhAGhoiYZzYnGJhktmWWZKqoZPal56SYZGIVidJlBlak5xKlSd0qOOeUqa1v//m//XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⍘Ｎ²θ
```

Input the number and convert it to base 2 as a string.

```
≔⁺№θ10№θ01η
```

Calculate the number of of switches by counting the occurrences of `10` or `01` in the string.

```
¿ηＩ∕Ｌθη∞
```

If the total is nonzero then output the smoothness otherwise print Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->n{1.0*(w=(n^n/2).digits 2).size/~-w.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2lDPQEuj3FYjLy5P30hTLyUzPbOkWAHIKs6sStWv0y3XKy7Nrf0fbapjaKBjqGOsYx6rl5tYUF1TUVOgkBZdEVv7HwA)

#### How?

First step: bitwise XOR of x and x/2. The result will have a bit set to 1 for every switch in the input number plus 1, and so we just need to get the number of digits in base 2, and their sum. Then add some parentheses, and make it a float.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 105 chars

```
def s(n):b=bin(n)[2:];l=len(b);c=sum([0if b[i]==b[i+1]else 1for i in range(l-1)]);return l/c if c>0else-1
```

Returns -1 in the case of an infinity.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 60 bytes

Port of [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)'s Ruby [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180999/64121).

```python
lambda l:(c:=(b:=bin(l^l>>1)).count('1'))>1and(len(b)-2)/~-c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLDsIgEADQ/ZyCXWcSq07rp5LASYwJ0GJJcNqQunDj1dG3f@tnmxfph7XUaO41u5cfncoagzbotfFJMD@ytUy0D8tbNmy4IbLsZMQ8CXpqOzp821DjUlRSSVRx8pyQd8ykQam1pH@LmIgqQwc9nOAMF7jCADfg4w8)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

Returns false if the value is infinite.

```python
k=input()
n=s=0
while k:l=k%2;n+=1.;k/=2;s+=l^k%2
print s>1and n/~-s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1PC4JAFMTv71M8hKCQ0t3@K6@bXbt0DkwXlJV1ebtSXvrqm1KnGYbfzNjRN72RoeprhYRRFAVNrbGDX67AkKMUXk3bKdRZR3ohcxOT2OQ6IZm7mLrHlIHl1nh0F1GaGk3yWbswDcG/eedBZYDoeZwFUb1VhfMhzL5S1mNxuxbMPf@AJ6tSBwEStrCDPRzgCCc4g0i/)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 42 bytes

```ruby
~:digits&2|:/%[:+@|Q,:chunk+I|A|:+@|:pred]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN7XqrFIy0zNLitWMaqz0VaOttB1qAnWskjNK87K1PWsca0ACVgVFqSmxEB07o011DA10DHWMdcxj9XITC6oLFNyi4w1jayHyCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 30 bytes

Outputs infinity `0w` for 1, 3, 7 etc.

```
{count[b]%-1+/differ b:2 vs x}
```

## k, 21 bytes

```
{(#x)%-1+/~~':x:2\:x}
```